# How to make a Image card and make it appear it on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I am very new to frontend development. I have created an ember app which has a feed page. The feed page is mainly consists of images and their associated likes and comments. Now what I want is when I click on images it should open the original size image and its likes and comments (Very much similar to Facebook's feed, when you click on images it opens a new window or card in which all information about it is present). Pinterest has similar behavior. How can I achieve the same thing? I am not very sure where look or start. Please give some examples and demos so that I can have a better understanding.

Comment: You question is very general - can you please share some concrete code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ember addon `ember-modal-dialog`](http://www.emberobserver.com/addons/ember-modal-dialog) for a straight forward way to achieve the 'new window' you are referring to. See the [demo here](https://yapplabs.github.io/ember-modal-dialog/). In general, [Ember Observer](http://www.emberobserver.com) is a good place to check for ember addons - particularly UI components that you can quickly leverage.